# Generate PDF of only one sheet of my spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I need a script that creates a PDF with only one sheet of my spreadsheet.
I currently have a script that generates a PDF but does it with the entire file.
I can not copy the values to another file, since the sheet I need to export is graphics with data extracted from another sheet.
Could you help me? Thank you.

```
function myFunction() {
  var archivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hoja = archivo.getSheetByName("Graficos 2");
  var id = archivo.getId();
  var archivoId = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var archivoBlob = archivoId.getBlob();
  var carpetaId = archivoId.getParents();
  var contenidoPDF = archivo.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  carpetaId.next().createFile(contenidoPDF);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been addressed more or less [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf).

In short, you can modify export parameters in Url queryString to get a specific sheet. And then convert the blob to a pdf.

Here is the code for the same, base code was obtained from [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf)

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "Your Email Id"; 

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("<Your Sheet name>")

  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "PDF generated from sheet " + sheet.getName(); 

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  var body = "Install the <a href='http://www.labnol.org/email-sheet'>Email Spreadsheet add-on</a> for one-click conversion.";

  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs;


    // Convert your specific sheet to blob
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');


  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments:[blobs]     
    });  
}
```

**Edit:** To combine specific sheets and convert it into and pdf.

Firstly you will have to obtain the sheet object of all the sheets you want to merge into the pdf

```
var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("<Your Sheet name>")
var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("<Your Sheet name>")
```

Then pass the sheetId of each of the sheet to the URL query delimited by `%EE%B8%80`, Like so

```
   url += url_ext + sheet.getSheetId()+ "%EE%B8%80"+sheet2.getSheetId()+ "%EE%B8%80"+sheet3.getSheetId()
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });
```

Comment: Why use GmailApp and MailApp? Just MailApp would be sufficient, and avoid users thinking your script wants to peek into their inbox :D

Comment: Thank you very much! I had already reviewed that page, but I did not manage to modify the scripts in the correct way.
Now, I have 2 more questions If you want to do that in a PDF, 3 sheets are saved, can it be done with the same script?
Second question. What does the line of code:
// Base URL
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId ());

Comment: @SantiagoRuffino could you please rephrase your question, not really sure what you are asking? Thanks.

Comment: If I wanted to generate a PDF with 3 sheets of my spreadsheet, using this same script. What would be the necessary modifications for the script? @JackBrown

Comment: @SantiagoRuffino I have updated the answer, which should provide a solution to your query